# java constructor, arrays and void methods

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, constructor, void

the objective of this assignment is to create a program that displays each students average grades using data from a text file. I've followed my professors guidelines but I still think I'm missing something or doing something wrong for the array list and one of the void methods. these are the guidelines:

Create a class named Student as follows. The class keeps track of the
student’s homework grades.

a. The instance (or member) private variables – name (String), homeworks
(an integer ArrayList).

b. A single constructor with name as its argument. Also, initialize the
homeworks arraylist.

c. The public get and set methods for the name instance variable.

d. A void addHomeworkGrade method which takes one argument – the
new homework grade.

e. A public computeAverage method which takes no arguments and
returns a double showing the average homework grade for this
student.

f. Override the toString method to return the string representation of this
object in the format “The ’s average grade is ”.

My code inserted below is from my Student class and I also will have another class called Test which contains the file reader and buffer reader to read the text file. Can someone please help me verify that this code looks correct especially the creating and initializing the array and the void addHomeworkGrade method. Thank you in advance.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Student {

// Declare the variables

private String name;
private int homework1;
private int homework2;
private int homework3;
private int homework4;
private int homework5;
private int homework6;

// Constructor

public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

//Create and initialize homeworks array list
ArrayList<Integer> homeworkList = new ArrayList<Integer>();


// setter or mutator methods change the field values
public void setName(String x) {
}

// Accessor or getter methods provide the field values
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

//A void addHomeworkGrade with one argument - to get homework grade
public String addHomeworkGrade() {

    DecimalFormat pattern = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    double homeworkGrade;
    homeworkGrade = (homework1 + homework2 + homework3 + homework4 + homework5 + homework6);
    return pattern.format(homeworkGrade);
}

// other methods perform operations on Employee data
public String computeAverage() {

    DecimalFormat pattern = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    double average;
    average = ((homework1 + homework2 + homework3 + homework4 + homework5 + homework6) / 6.00);
    return pattern.format(average);
}

// Override the toString method to return the string representation
public String toString() {
    return (getName() + "'s average grade is " + computeAverage());

}
```

}

Comment: You don't seem to have a question, only a request.

Comment: why would you make an arraylist and then not even use it?

Comment: Why do you use homeworkX variables when you have to use list of grades?

Comment: wants stackoverflow to do his homework

Comment: Use your `ArrayList`, and replace `6.00` with its size (since hardcoded values are bad). And by use it I mean fill it and replace all x+y+z code. Sum its contents using a loop of some kind

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, is just have the list, not the individual variables. Then your method 'addHomeworkGrade' needs to take in an integer, add it into the list, it doesn't need to return anything. Then in 'computeAverage' you add all the values together from the list, divide by its length, and return it. Does this make sense? i can provide code snippets if you want (but don't want to write the whole thing for you).

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say but producing it into code is another story. If you wouldn't mind providing code snippets that would be much appreciated.

Comment: ok, so an ArrayList is a dynamic sized list of objects, in your case, numbers. What this means you can do, is put all of your grades into it, and you have as many grades as the student has. I imagine when you first got the skeleton class the add method looked like this: public void addHomeworkGrade(int grade). What you need to do in this method is take the passed in grade, and add it into the list. you do this using the .add method on your ArrayList. (the int may well have been an Integer). That's your first step.

Comment: btw, 'a void method' is a method that doesn't return anything

Comment: Once you have that, now you need to compute the average. To do this you need to loop through the arraylist (please go and google how to do this, its quite straight forward) adding all the values together as you go. then you divide the result, by the number of elements in your arraylist (which you find out using '.size()'), and return the result.

Comment: Yes, I totally understand that you can do it that way, but I think my professor is asking me to do is take those homework values from a text using a file reader and buffer reader which is currently stored in another class. I don't think he wants us to insert the values into the ArrayList initially. Does that make sense

Comment: When you read them from your text file, you would then call student.addHomeworkGrade(valuefromfile).

Comment: okay let me give that a try and I will let you know if I was able to figure it out. Thank you